# Short story about a guy getting a phone call from himself

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I'm looking for an anthology about time travel that includes a particular story.  The guy is in an apartment and gets a phone call from himself.  It goes through a series of attempts at proving or disproving that this is really happening.  Sound familiar?

Comment: Hi there! :) this is still a bit vague - could you take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] into your question? For instance, when did you read that? Was it English? Do you remember what the cover looked like? Every info's good to take to increase the chances of a successful identification. Cheers!

Comment: The story does indeed sound familiar to me, but unfortunately I don't think I read it in an anthology. I may have read it in a magazine, Analog or Fantasy and Science Fiction (or possibly Asimov's) - if so, then it would have been published somewhere in the 1988-1995 range, in all likelihood. I've seen multiple references to a Murray Leinster short story, I believe titled "Sam, This Is You". I don't think that's the story I'm thinking of, but it might be worth your checking into.

Comment: Ellison's Shatterday is a story about guy who, whole out and about, accidentally calls his own home number...and he answers.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the anthology, maybe the cover design or some of the other stories?

Comment: I found "Sam, this is you", and that's not it.   I read the story someplace between 10 & 20 years ago, but for some reason it sticks with me... and that story is really what I remember from the anthology.  I say anthology because that is what I was reading then... seldom reading magazines.  The story takes place over a fairly short time period.  A day?  I seem to remember that he left his apartment, went to a corner store, and called home... that was the phone call he originally received a little while earlier.

Answer (score 13):

["*Sam, This is You*"](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/32324/32324-h/32324-h.htm) by Murray Leinster.

> Sam, This is You appeared in the May 1955 issue of Galaxy Science Fiction.
>
> Sam had led a peaceful and impecunious life—until a voice cut in on a phone and said: Sam, this is You...
>
> <sub>[Goodreads, Sam, This is You](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8599107-sam-this-is-you)</sub>

The Anthology was probably ["*Twists in Time*"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?636230).